# How many model parameters do we need to optimize for the following CNN model?

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, machine-learning-model

We use the following convolutional neural network to classify a set of 32×32 greyscale images (so the input size will be 32$\times$32$\times$1):

1. Layer 1: convolutional layer with the ReLU nonlinear activation function, 100 5×5 filters with stride 1.
2. Layer 2: 2×2 max-pooling layer
3. Layer 3: convolutional layer with the ReLU nonlinear activation function, 50  3×3 filters with stride 1.
4. Layer 4: 2×2 max-pooling layer
5. Layer 5: fully-connected layer
6. Layer 6: classification layer

How many model parameters do we need to optimize in the first layer and in the second layer (assume the bias term is used)

Comment: Which library are you using ?

Comment: That's a general question it is not using any libraries in Python, just I wanted to know the number of parameters after each layer we have to optimize

Comment: 32*32*1

width m, height n, previous layer’s filters d 

 k in the current layer

((m * n * d)+1)* k)=((5*5*1)+1)*100)=260 in first layer and the second layer This has got no learnable parameters because all it does is calculate a specific number, no backprop learning involved! Thus number of parameters = 0. but am not sure and need to be confirmed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use tensorflow to display the number of trainable parameters:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers

def make_model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(100, (5, 5), strides=1,input_shape=[32, 32, 1]))
    model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

    return model

model=make_model()

model.summary()
```

This gives 2600 trainable params and 0 non-trainable params.

Comment: ((5*5*1)+1)*100)=2600 so it is for first layer and the second layer which is max-pooling This has got no learnable parameters because all it does is calculate a specific number, no backdrop learning involved! Thus a number of parameters = 0. is it right?

Comment: Yes, 0 for the second layer!

Comment: all good, don't forget to accept the answer if you found it useful!